# My modal only works on the first image but not on the rest of the images?

Tags: javascript

The modal only works on the first image but not on the rest of the images.
I tried to change the img var to getElementsByClassName but it didn't work as well. I need to find out why it only work on one id and not not on the rest of the id. Is there any js code that I am missing?

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('img_1');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal_image {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal_image:hover {opacity: 0.7;}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform: scale(0.1)}
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<img class="modal_image" id="img_1" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_2" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_3" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_4" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_5" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. `Id` not work with multiple selector.Class work with multiple selector.So use with `for loop` it will apply each onclick of the class element of `img`.

Best use with **[addEventListener('click',function () {})](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)** instead of `element.onclick`

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a cap
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('modal_image');
for(var i=0; i<img.length; i++){
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
})
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.modal_image {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.modal_image:hover {opacity: 0.7;}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform: scale(0.1)}
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<img class="modal_image" id="img_1" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_2" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_3" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_4" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">
<img class="modal_image" id="img_5" src="https://www.nordicvisitor.com/images/iceland/winter/northern-lights-lake-thingvellir-national-park-iceland.jpg" alt="Northern Lights, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close">×</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did this and it works on all image but the close button doesn't work anymore

addEventListener('click',function () {
 modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
});

Comment: yes ...the same thing added with my answer.see the answer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: Close button working see with answer.where is not working

Comment: I see..there was a bug on my end. Thanks a lot!

Comment: if the answer is satisfied .please [mark as answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) is placed on left of the answer.Because its helpful for future visitors